# Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread - ObjectiveC Error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a tab bar view to get map addresses - however, after a couple of times, it will crash with the error

```
Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.

This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.
```

Having searched this up, it is coming from this method

```
-(void)showGoMap{
    
     
        self.mapView.hidden = NO;
        int randomIndex = arc4random() % [arr_OfCountryCode count];

       
    
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=false,+CA&key=MY_API_KEY",
                             [arr_OfCountryCode objectAtIndex:randomIndex]];
       
       
          
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
        NSLog(@"Sending request");
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Response Received");
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
            } else {
                
                NSDictionary *jsonObject=[NSJSONSerialization
                                          JSONObjectWithData:data
                                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                          error:nil];
                
                NSLog(@"Data: %@", jsonObject);
                NSString *responseStatus = [[jsonObject objectForKey:@"status"] lowercaseString];
                NSLog(@"Status: %@", responseStatus);
                  
                if (![responseStatus isEqualToString:@"ok"]) {
                    
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                         ^{
                    
                    UIAlertController *limitExceededAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Not working This Time!" message:@"Try Again" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"I'll Try Again Shortly" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
                        
                        
                        
                    }];
                    [limitExceededAlert addAction:okAction];
               
                    [self presentViewController:limitExceededAlert animated:true completion:nil];
                    });
                    
                    return;
                    
                }
                   
                NSDictionary *places = [[[[jsonObject objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"geometry"] objectForKey:@"location"];
                NSDictionary *locations = [[[jsonObject objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"address_components"];
                
                float lat = [[places objectForKey:@"lat"] floatValue];
                float lon = [[places objectForKey:@"lng"] floatValue];

                MKCoordinateRegion region;
                MKCoordinateSpan span;
                span.latitudeDelta = 0.50;
                span.longitudeDelta = 0.50;
                
                location.latitude = lat;
                location.longitude = lon;
                region.span = span;
                region.center = location;
                [self.mk_MapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
                
                NSString *str_Title = [[locations valueForKey:@"long_name"] objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *str_Short = [[locations valueForKey:@"short_name"] objectAtIndex:0];
                
                MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
                point.coordinate = location;
                point.title = str_Title;
                point.subtitle = str_Short;
                [self.mk_MapView addAnnotation:point];
                
                 
            }
        }];
 
    
    
}
```

As you can see in the code method I have already used

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                         ^{
```

Which I thought would fix, but unfortunately still happens. It always works first time, the crash occurs only on the 2nd or 3rd attempt to load the mapview again.

Comment: Only the alert code is on the main queue. The map view code is not and it needs to be.

Comment: I stared for so long at the code... And you solved it right away! Thank you! - @HangarRash